# Is there a way to automatically find the product of a column based on other columns

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Is there a way to automatically find the product of a column based on other columns.

I have a database table called posts

> Post Table

- id
- user_id
- rank  = affinity x weight x decay
- affinity
- weight
- decay

how do I make this happen rank = affinity x weight x decay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the easiest way in MySQL is to define a view that does the calculation:

```
create view v_t as
    select t.*, (affinity*weight*decay) as rank
    from t;
```

You can then use the view instead of the table in your code, and the value will be there.

Comment: what do you mean view?
view in mvc?
or something in mysql?

Comment: It depends. If using MySQL 5.7.6+, then there are also GENERATED COLUMNS, which might be easier in this case. They are pretty new, I think, and I only heard of them by chance ;-)

Comment: @sadbeginner Gordon means a [MySQL VIEW](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html). You can think of it as a _predefined select statement_ (predefined by you) which is stored in the DB and can be used like a table as long as you only _select_ from it. There are also VIEWS that can be inserted into, but then it gets complicated. With Gordon's view you can e.g. `select * from v_t` or `select user_id from v_t where rank=15`.

Comment: @PerlDog I did this create view v_t as
    select t.*, (affinity*weight*decay) as rank
    from t;
is this virtual or stored?

Comment: @sadbeginner Don't confuse VIEWs and GENERATED COLUMNS, they are two different things, they just _feel_ the same in your case. A VIEW is always (kind of) _virtual_ because no data is stored, only the underlying select statement (literally). So `select * from v_t` is exactly the same as if you had typed `select t.*, (affinity*weight*decay) as rank from t`. A VIEW is built _on top_ of a table while GENERATED COLUMNS are _inside_ (part of) the table.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using MySQL 5.7.6, then you could also use `GENERATED COLUMNS`

From the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html) (you must scroll down to the section "CREATE TABLE and Generated Columns"):

> As of MySQL 5.7.6, CREATE TABLE supports the specification of
>   generated columns.

Generated columns can either be

- *virtual*, i.e. calculated on the fly when the column is read, similar to a view like @GordonLinoff suggested

or

- *stored*, i.e. they occupy space in the DB and get calculated each time the rows are inserted or updated

Example:

```
-- calculated on-the-fly when reading:
create table post (
    id       int,
    user_id  varchar(20),
    affinity int,
    weight   int,
    decay    int,
    RANK     int GENERATED ALWAYS AS (affinity*weight*decay) VIRTUAL
);
```

or

```
-- calculated during insert/update:
create table post (
    id       int,
    user_id  varchar(20),
    affinity int,
    weight   int,
    decay    int,
    RANK     int GENERATED ALWAYS AS (affinity*weight*decay) STORED
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The calculation you present has an intrinsic issue (probably, or at least this is my understanding) because by having different values for the `affinity`, `weight` and `decay` you may end up with the same result, for instance 3 X 4 X 5 = 5 X 3 X 4. As a result, if you attempt to find records whose rank is, say, 60, you will get at least two (using the example above). Is this what you are looking for? If not, it would appear much clearer to generate a **composed** rank, something like `aaa-bbb-ccc` where `aaa` corresponds to the `affinity` (range 000-999), and so forth.
And yet, the **view** solution proposed above would not be recommended because it would trigger calculations every time you query it.

Another alternative would be to set triggers on these three fields such that, whenever any of the fields' value changes, the rank field would be re-calculated and deployed in the corresponding column.

Comment: how do I set the triggers?

Comment: Check this [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html). The idea would be to add a **rank** column to the table and set triggers on each of the three fields used to calculate  the rank, such that whenever a value to any of the fields is defined/change, a calculation will take place and the resulting rank value deployed in the new column. BE CAREFUL NOT TO SET A TRIGGER INTO THE NEW FIELD!!!